# SVN commit popup disappers

Tags: git-svn

I am using an ubuntu system & Rabbit SVN. I am trying to commit huge files on an SVN Server. When I click on the "OK" button on the SVN commit window, it starts processing and committing those files. After 2 minutes that window disappears without displaying any error message.

Comment: If you look at the repo on the server, what state does it end up in?

Comment: What is your question? Are you uncertain if the commit worked? Do you know if it did?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check the log of the SVN server (usually Apache) to see what is going on (they are not visible directly from a client-side [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/) GUI.

Usually, such a listener includes a size limit for any given web request: if it is too big, it would return an error, which might end up *not* being display by the client (your RbbitVCS).